# Google Sign In Website Using Custom Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-oauth, google-signin

I have implemented Google Sign In for my website by following the official tutorial of Google : 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Using the above tutorial I'm getting the following button

[image: Google signin]

Now I'm trying to Change the text of the button from "Sign In" to "Connect with Google" But nothing is happening..

My Javascript code..

```
           function onSignIn(googleUser) {

            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            loginpassword = profile.getId();
            loginemail =  profile.getEmail();
        };
```

HTML Code..

```
     <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">Connect with Google</div>
```

Any idea how to change the text? Even though I'm providing the client ID and the external link for platform.js file it's still not working..Please Help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The platform.js library from google is rendering the button, along with the text.

In order to override it, you need to [build your own custom button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button).  From Google's example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script>
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
          document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #customBtn {
      display: inline-block;
      background: #4285f4;
      color: white;
      width: 190px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #customBtn:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    span.label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    span.icon {
      background: url('{{path to your button image}}') transparent 5px 50% no-repeat;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
      border-right: #2265d4 1px solid;
    }
    span.buttonText {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-left: 42px;
      padding-right: 42px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      /* Use the Roboto font that is loaded in the <head> */
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
```

Note that you can find the actual icon file [on Google's server for download](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png).

Once you've set the styles and the Javascript, you would call the button itself through `HTML`, at which point you can specify the text:

```
  <body>
  <!-- In the callback, you would hide the gSignInWrapper element on a
  successful sign in -->
  <div id="gSignInWrapper">
    <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
    <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <script>startApp();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you must comply with [Google's branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines).

Comment: This mostly works, however their example is incomplete in that the Google icon URL is a URI relative to the web page's server. The example works when served from the Google developers' site as the icon exists, but will not by default for anyone testing this on their own server. Google's zip with branded content does not include the icon, and there is no discussion for where to obtain official icons.

Comment: @Nick I have edited to clarify that the sample URL included with Google's sample code must point to a valid image file.  The sample icon [is available for download](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png) from Google.

Comment: Thanks, and not knocking your example at all as it's Google's documentation failing here in just having the icon as part of an example and not at any official location as such. Was expecting them to provide an icon set similar to the zip for the full button renderings, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, their branding files, and the wording of the branding guidelines for making your own, are pretty confusing.  You can't change the size of the icon, but if you want to create a custom icon of a different size, use the example sizes...  huh?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just change the span text which is generated using Javascript, Try this
replace your Div id with 'DivID' in the code

```js
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#DivID div div span span:last').text("Sign up with Google");
        $('#DivID div div span span:first').text("Sign up with Google");
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

For instance, here is the HTML section:

```
<div id="GoogeSigninButton" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" class="g-signin2"></div>
```

then for the script tag following the button code, it looks like this:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#GoogeSigninButton div div span span:last').text("Custom Sign in Text");
        $('#GoogeSigninButton div div span span:first').text("Custom Sign in Text");
        $('#GoogeSigninButton div div span span:last').css("font-family", "Arial");//for font formatting
        $('#GoogeSigninButton div div span span:first').css("font-family", "Arial");//for font formatting
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

After the page has loaded for around 10 seconds, it will change the button's text to the custom text and font you want.